# "Space" issue in factor output in R

Tags: r

[image]

Hey there. Why am I seeing "" in the levels even though I replaced them with NA? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to remove the unused levels with `droplevels`

```
duplicate_na_recode_V3 <- droplevels(duplicate_na_recode_V3)
```